# In R and knitr, can I suppress the message of readOGR?

Tags: r, knitr, ogr

I'm building small report using R & knitr, sending the output to pdf.

I'm using several shape files in my analysis and whenever I use `readOGR` function of `rgdal` package I get information on what is being read, for instance:

```
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: "__PATH_HERE__", layer: "__NAME__OF__LAYER__HERE__"
with 148 features and 5 fields
Feature type: wkbPolygon with 2 dimensions
```

Normally, it's useful thing to have.. but unfortunately it also prints out in my pdf output.

I tried setting knitr's chunk options to `echo=FALSE, message=FALSE` but unfortunately it did't help.

Any better solution to that?

Comment: you got two better solutions, but when everything else fails (ie print message in C code, and knitr chunk that you want to see other output from), I found that `capture.output` can be useful.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Have you tried setting `verbose = FALSE` in the `readOGR` function itself?

e.g.

```
> dsn <- system.file("vectors", package = "rgdal")[1]
> cities <- readOGR(dsn=dsn, layer="cities")
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: "C:/Users/sohanlon/Dropbox/R/R64_Win_Libs/rgdal/vectors", layer: "cities"
with 606 features and 4 fields
Feature type: wkbPoint with 2 dimensions
# Set verbose = FALSE
> cities <- readOGR(dsn=dsn, layer="cities" , verbose = FALSE)
```

The relevant knitr chunk, then, could be:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(rgdal)
dsn <- system.file("vectors", package = "rgdal")[1]
cities <- readOGR(dsn=dsn, layer="cities", verbose=FALSE)
```
````

Comment: +1 for `verbose = FALSE`. I like `results = "hide"` because it is a bit more transparent.

Comment: @SimonO101 Doh. I didn’t realize I should be looking at solution on readOGR side. All working now. Thanks.

Comment: For reference, in `sf` use `quiet = TRUE`

Answer (score 11):

The "knitr" way to do this would be to use `results = 'hide'`. Borrowing from @SimonO101's example data, try:

````
```{r, results='hide', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(rgdal)
dsn <- system.file("vectors", package = "rgdal")[1]
cities <- readOGR(dsn=dsn, layer="cities")
```
````

Comment: Does that hide the actual commands too? Which might be what the OP wants of course.

Comment: @SimonO101, Sure. But then then just change it to `echo=TRUE` to see the code that was entered.

Comment: Ah cool. Getting better with `knitr` is on my to do list. It's funny how everything moves ON to my to do list, but never seems to move OFF it. +1 for the knitr way.

Comment: Thanks - I like that results = "hide" still lets me see my images/maps in the final documnent.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `st_read` instead of `readOGR` use `quiet=TRUE` as an additional parameter to hide the logs